# What happens if you do not click the Mysterious stranger in time in Fallout Shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

What would happens if you don't click that mystery man on time in Fallout Shelter? Every time he shows up I'm always scared that I miss him while I'm still looking. Will he even do anything to my dwellers or vault or will he just disappear?

Answer (score 8):

He just disappears. The only purpose he serves is to give you bonus caps if you manage to find him, and click on him in time.

As your vault grows, this will become more and more difficult.